# Fetching a score associated with a date 'Around' 7 days ago

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, zoo

This is what my dataframe looks like. The rightmost(4th) column is my desired column. For a given name,I am trying to derive that person' score from 7 days ago. If no date exists exactly 7 days ago, then I want the score associated with whatever date is closest to (a row's date- 7 days).

```
library(data.table)
 dt <- fread('
    Name      Score     Date         ScoreAround7DaysAgo
    John       9       2016-01-01       NA
    John       6       2016-01-10       9
    John       3       2016-01-17       6
    John       5       2016-01-18       6
    Tom        9       2016-01-01       NA
    Tom        6       2016-01-10       9
    Tom        3       2016-01-17       6
    Tom        5       2016-01-18       6
                                ')
dt[, Date := as.IDate(Date)]
```

I have tried `dt[dt,roll=7+nearest]` to no avail. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dt[, val := .SD[.(Name = Name, Date = Date - 7), on = c('Name', 'Date'), roll = 'nearest',
                c(NA, tail(Score, -1)), by = Name]$V1]
dt
#   Name Score       Date ScoreAround7DaysAgo val
#1: John     9 2016-01-01                  NA  NA
#2: John     6 2016-01-10                   9   9
#3: John     3 2016-01-17                   6   6
#4: John     5 2016-01-18                   6   6
#5:  Tom     9 2016-01-01                  NA  NA
#6:  Tom     6 2016-01-10                   9   9
#7:  Tom     3 2016-01-17                   6   6
#8:  Tom     5 2016-01-18                   6   6
```

Answer (score 5):

This works:

```
dt[, DateLag := Date - 7L ]
w = dt[dt, which = TRUE, on = c("Name", Date = "DateLag"), roll = "nearest"]

dt[ , `:=`(ScoreLag = Score[replace(w, w == .I, NA_integer_)], DateLag = NULL)]


   Name Score       Date ScoreAround7DaysAgo ScoreLag
1: John     9 2016-01-01                  NA       NA
2: John     6 2016-01-10                   9        9
3: John     3 2016-01-17                   6        6
4: John     5 2016-01-18                   6        6
5:  Tom     9 2016-01-01                  NA       NA
6:  Tom     6 2016-01-10                   9        9
7:  Tom     3 2016-01-17                   6        6
8:  Tom     5 2016-01-18                   6        6
```

It finds the nearest date to `Date-7`, but discards it if it is the same `Date` again.

Comment: Thank you Frank for your answer. I get an error" Error in forderv(x, by = rightcols) : 
  'by' value -2147483648 out of range [1,5]" when I execute the second line. I also have change Date data type from character to date for the first line to run.

Comment: I already modified your question so there's a date there (can't see any reason to use a character). Are you running version 1.9.6+ of the package? I think it should work. (I used `IDate` rather than `Date`, but I don't think that should matter.)

Comment: Thank you Frank. I updated R from 3.2.3 to 3.2.5 but still an error. my data.table is 1.9.6. When I change Date='DatelLag" to just Datelag, it runs but all NAs show up in the result set. I may be missing something. But thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: @gibbz00 Np. Maybe try it again after Arun's edit. I don't know where that error is coming from.

Comment: @Arun Thanks for the edit. I'm still learning the rolling-join options. Is my new final sentence accurate ("It finds the nearest date to Date-7, but returns NA if Date-7 is not in the range of dates observed.")? Also, is there a way to do this as a merge-assign (I mean in one step, instead of two)?

Comment: No luck with Arun's edit either. This is weird and frustrating. eddi's solution gives me the results I am looking for. Both solutions look great, but not knowing what is returning the error is a little demoralizing.

Comment: @gibbz00 your error indicates you're providing incorrect column names... (I think this error message is fixed to be more useful currently).

Comment: @Frank, rolled back the answer, as `rollends=FALSE` would return `NA` if `Date-7` falls before the first value.. which is not desirable. e.g., if the 2nd Date for first group was, `2016-01-02`, we need to get `9` for it.. See the definition of *rollends* in `?data.table`. I think it is quite clear.

Comment: @Frank, on the 1-step instead of 2 -- good point.. wouldn't that be great! Will look into it..